# My 25 lb dog took my 45 lb dogs heart and thyroid medication

Tags: health

My 25 lb dog took my 45 lb dogs heart and thyroid medication. What possible symptoms should I be looking for if poisoning has occurred?

Comment: Please call your vet right away. All trouble with meds require a professional to tell you what to do. Randos on the internet are unlikely to be able to give you good advice.